# Для чего используются методы, которые мы не вызываем?

Tags: java

Я пишу на Bukkit'e и посмотрев как пишется код в других плагинах, часто замечаю как часто пишут вот такой код (код прикрепил), ведь мы эти методы создаём, но не вызываем их, как это работает? И можно как нибудь по другому его объявить? Так же в главном классе, который следует `JavaPlugin` в методе `onEnable()` пишется такая фраза

```
Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Example(), this);


public class Example implements Listener {
     @EventHandler
     public void onUsing(PlayerInteractEvent event) {}
}
```

Comment: Даже если мы не вызываем метод, его может вызвать кто-то другой. В данном случае у вас обработчик событий, см. [Событие (объектно-ориентированное программирование)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Событие_(объектно-ориентированное_программирование))

Answer (score 1):

Вы расширили класс интерфейсом. Вы своего рода заключаете контракт, что этот метод в любом случае будет присутствовать в данном классе.